# How can I remove '\n' every time it is in one of my lists [Python]

Tags: python-3.x

When I get my strings from a .txt file and put them in a list '\n' always seems to be popping up at the end, is there any way i can remove these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove the newline character in a list read from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319236/remove-the-newline-character-in-a-list-read-from-a-file), or [Reading a file without newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines)

Comment: without code its hard to tell - but the dupe sounds plausible