# Create a string list into a float list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I was reading from a file and was able to compute a list, but sadly it reads as :
**['40\n', '35\n', '49\n', '53\n', '38\n', '39\n', '40\n', '37\n', '49\n', '34\n', '38\n', '43\n', '47\n', '\n']**
when I would like it to read as:
**['40', '35', '49', '53', '38', '39', '40', '37', '49', '34', '38', '43', '47']**
I know I have to append it and/or slice it in order to turn in into floats. I am really stuck on this part. This is the one part that will make the rest of my code work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the code you used to read from the file?

Comment: Show us your code and data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319236/remove-the-newline-character-in-a-list-read-from-a-file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-a-trailing-newline

Answer (score 1):

'\n' is a linebreak. It can be ignored when there is a number before it. Thus you could do:

```
a = ['40\n', '35\n', '49\n', '53\n', '38\n', '39\n', '40\n', '37\n', '49\n', '34\n', '38\n', '43\n', '47\n', '\n']

[int(i) for i in a if i!='\n']
[40, 35, 49, 53, 38, 39, 40, 37, 49, 34, 38, 43, 47]
```

if you want floats, just do:

```
[float(i) for i in a if i!='\n']
[40.0, 35.0, 49.0, 53.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0, 37.0, 49.0, 34.0, 38.0,
```

43.0, 47.0]

Comment: If my file is called "content" would it be [float(content) for content in a if (content)!='\n']

Comment: @NewHere NO. you cannot do that. `i` is not a file but rather an index. You should first read the file into python and iterate over the lines

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['40\n', '35\n', '49\n', '53\n', '38\n', '39\n', '40\n', '37\n', '49\n', '34\n', '38\n', '43\n', '47\n', '\n']

float_a = [float(x[:-1]) for x in a if x != '\n']
```

You can easily convert this list with a list comprehension to a list of floats.